# how to add a data source as loop count in vs2010 web performance test

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance-testing

I would like to add a loop in one of step on my web performance test of vs2010. 
However, I try to add a data source (database) as a parameter and set this parameter as loop count but fail. 
I have check all msdn online document but found none answer. 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

solved, I record web performance test and then generate code from it. after code file generated, I manually adjust this code file